# SQL Statement return count = 0 even if WHERE statement is not met

Tags: sql, database

I ran into a problem where my sql query is not selecting the tuples that do not met the where statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g.genre) 
FROM movie m 
     JOIN genre g ON (m.movie_id = g.movie_id) 
WHERE g.genre IN ('Animation', 'Comedy', 'Family')
```

This will return number of common genres between the movie and my genre list. The objective is to return 0 even though there is nothing in common. However, the query will skips those tuples from the movie table as they do not meet the WHERE clause requirements.

Any ideas how to reconstruct my query so that i can achieve my goal, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation is hard to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Skip the `WHERE` clause to get "*those tuples from the movie table as they do not meet the WHERE clause requirements*". Instead use a `case` expression to do conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT case when g.genre IN ('Animation', 'Comedy', 'Family') then g.genre end) 
FROM movie m 
     JOIN genre g ON (m.movie_id = g.movie_id)
```